# Ring of polynomials as free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is it true that $R=k[x,y]$ is a free $R$-module ?

I think that it isn't true. Natural candidate for the base is $\{x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}\}_{\alpha,\beta}$, but :

$x\cdot (xy) +(-y)\cdot x^2 =0$

and $x\neq 0,\ -y \neq 0$.

Comment: P Vanchinathan has answered your question below. I just want to add that $R$ is also free, when considered as a $k$-module (i.e. a k-vector space, assuming $k$ is a field). Then your linear combination doesn't work since it is not a k-linear combination. As a $k$-module you have indeed supplied a possible choice of basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused $k$-vector space basis as  $R$-module basis, hence this issue.

ANy commutative ring  is a free module overitself with basis the singleton $\{1\}$, consiting of the multiplicative identity.

Given two elements $a,b\in $R, by commutativity we have $a.b -b.a=0$ and so a basis has to have less than 2 elements.